# bash alias that emulates Finder's archive with ditto?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, macos

So I find it useful to have a function defined in my shell such as the following:

```
zip() { ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent "$1" "$1.zip" }
```

How would I extend this to take any number of args and then, if there is more than one argument, it would archive them all into Archive.zip and if that filename is already taken it will save it as Archive-1.zip, Archive-2.zip, or Archive-n.zip?

Comment: `ditto: Can't archive multiple sources`.  You would likely either need to create a new directory and add all your source files to that directory and then archive it or just use zip(1)

Comment: Hmmm. Is there a way to get a one-to-one zip result that emulates the way Finder archives them? I've read before that `ditto` was the only real option, but perhaps there's a way to coax `zip` into working more like it...

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference between `zip` and finder is.  They seem identical in my testing.

Comment: Also can you clarify what you mean by "finder's archive" are you talking about the ability to right click and "compress"?  Or the actual archive utility (not finder at all)?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea of how to go about your question. I have not tested this one

```
zippo() {  
  local n=1
  local f
  for f; do
     if [[ -e $f.zip ]]; then
      echo ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent "$f" "${f}-${n}.zip"
      ((n++))  
     else 
      echo ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent "$f" "$f.zip"
     fi
   done
 }
```

Like I said untested but the echo is there just to make sure you get the right output. I don't have `ditto` so I can't really test it.

Comment: It seems like OP wants multiple files to go into the same archive.zip